# No audio output in ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: sound

I am not getting any audio output in ubuntu 18.04.2. What should I do? I have tried installing pavucontrol, alsa-mixer, also force reloaded the alsa but nothing worked for me?

Answer (score 0):

If you have connected some HDMI cable before this problem, probably you can solve connecting again the cable and change the audio output.
Or check Pulseaudio software to solve it.
I solve it testing both options.